# Reading Excel Files In C# Always Results In System.__ComObject?

Tags: c#, excel

This is the code I'm using to read an xls file:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets excelSheets = excelWorkbook.Worksheets;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet excelSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item(1);

MessageBox.Show(excelSheet.Cells[1,1].ToString());
```

Which results in a message box with:

```
System.__ComObject
```

Not sure what's going on, I'd really appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Range

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range =(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)excelSheet.Cells[1,1];
string cellValue =range.Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

In your example, excelSheet.Cells[1,1] is not a value but an object (Range).  You need to get the Value property of the object.

```
MessageBox.Show(excelSheet.Cells[1, 1].Value.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

In my project I use Value2:

```
 MessageBox.Show(((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)excelSheet.Cells[1, 1]).Value2.ToString());
```